# Pikaday - Different events with different colors

Tags: calendar, pikaday

I want to specify the color of the event when I add it to my calendar.

For example

> I can add an event and set it to a specific color using CSS
>   (.has-event) but this makes all my events the same color. I want to
>   add two different events and each event has one color (yellow and
>   green).

I can add events to the calendar by using the events configuration in one of the two form:

```
events: ['Sat Jun 28 2014'], or 
events: [{ date: new Date('Sat Jun 28 2014'), backgroundColor: '#FDD800', color: '#FFFFFF' }],
```

I would think that the latest one would be the one to solve my problem but it's not working.
Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can see the different colours only when you change the view from say monthly to daily. I had the problem and it seems this is a limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by building a style tag in the document, there is no flashing using css.

```css
<style>
    [data-pika-year="2021"][data-pika-month="3"][data-pika-day="20"] {
        color: white;
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>
```